# Why would color be different between browsers and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, safari

I have an rgb color set and it renders different between chrome and safari...I want it to look like the color rendered in safari but don't want it to make safari look too green if I adjust it..how can I make color consistently match across browsers?

```
.container-full {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(118, 198, 95);
    overflow: hidden;
```

[image]
[image]

edit addon 1:  This first occurred to me  while using a hex color as shown here, the photos I simply set it to rgba to rule out the fact that it was hex color...here is a side by side photo together with the page refreshed to show the live css uses the same value:

[image]

Comment: In Safari, the color has an alpha of 0.99

Comment: The only reason I can think of why this would be is you have a library that maybe modifying your CSS. [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is a great CSS reset tool, but I see you're using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I don't think this problem is related to vendor prefix's but if so you could give [Prefix-free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) a try.

Comment: Is it possible you could post your code on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: @Psioniax, while a different alpha would result in a different looking color, alpha `.99` is way too small of a difference to render such big color variations as shown in the pics. There must be something else.

Comment: @Chris you're right, but I don't see anything else that could cause the problem, by only looking at the screenshots

Comment: There may be a difference in colour management settings betwene the two browsers. Maybe [this website](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3738355) will clear things up.